# nextjs images from external links are not displayed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am fetching images from external server which are not displayed. I have configured next.config.js file as

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['ronakpatel.com'],
    deviceSizes: [320, 480, 600, 768, 900, 1024, 1200, 1440, 1920],
  }
};
```

For eg: In my code, I am using img tag as

```
<img src="https://ronakpatel.com/assets/abc.png" alt="Food" />
```

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Are you sure that the link works? Can you open it in your browser?

Comment: Yes , it works I have opened it in browser

Comment: I feel its CORS issue. But how do I resolve that

Comment: Have you checked your network tab for the response of the request?

Comment: In console, I get this Logo.png:1 GET https://ronakpatel.com/assets/Logo.png 499

Comment: Surprising thing is Network request is not made for images

Comment: 499 -> *This code is introduced to log the case when the connection is closed by client while HTTP server is processing its request, making server unable to send the HTTP header back*

Comment: How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Can you show more code around where the image is being used? Also, if you're adding a config for `next/image` why are you using the `<img>` tag?

Comment: This is not a NextJs issue. This is an issue with the https://ronakpatel.com/assets/abc.png not being accessible (at least publicly). I receive a network connection refused error trying to access the image.